# Print webpage from vb.net

Tags: html, vb.net, printing

I am trying to write a code in vb.net that can print a webpage url to a printer.

I also would like to choose which printer.

This is the code i have so far.

```
`
Dim pr As New ProcessStartInfo
pr.FileName = "chrome.exe"
pr.Arguments = "http://www.google.com"
Process.Start(pr)
```

`

This open the webpage in chrome.
It also works with internet explorer if i change to iexplorer.exe instead.
But i can not make it print the webpage.
I have searched the internet but i can not find anything what would work.

Anybody who knows ?

Comment: I have tried another approach of this problem.
Instead i now try to use a webbrowser controller and print from this.
i then use webbrowser.print command.
This work if it's html.
But the webpage i am trying to print is a aspx page with a pdf.
It's the pdf file that i want to be printed.
When i try this it is only the text that is in html that also exist on the page that is printed.
The pdf is not printed.
Then tried this i had to use WebBrowser.ShowPrintPreviewDialog for it to print anything.
So how should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Printing through Chrome will be easy if you prompt PrintFileDialog but for printing the file to PDF, i suggest you to use Universal Document Converter tool that has virtual PDF printer or similar to this tool.

Other method is to do the stuff, this link will help you!
[MSDN - Printing a Rendered webpage](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9d1a59c9-0e3c-4221-9fbe-6217dc8d3c84/how-to-better-print-a-rendered-html-document-in-vbnet-this-code-works-but-i-dont-like-it?forum=Vsexpressvb)

Comment: I don't know how to use Printfiledialog for chrome and i don't want to print to PDF.
Instead i want to print an PDF that exist on a webpage.
I tried the code on the link you gave me but i get same result as using webbrowser controll and showprintpreviewdialog.
Only the top og the webpage with a little text is printed , not the pdf.
I think the problem is that the pdf on the webpage is streamed from a SQL server.
But the strange thing is that webbrowser controller is showing the PDF without problem.

Comment: Actually pdf that is loaded to webbrowser is actually group of data that is rendered at the time of preview.